# Unable to resolve target 'android-14'

Tags: android, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error:Unable to resolve target ‘android-2’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942144/errorunable-to-resolve-target-android-2)

I was trying to add admob in my application. I updated android tools and sdk to the latest versions. But im getting this error "Unable to resolve target 'android-14'"

Comment: Make sure the sdk is installed in the proper location. Can you choose android-14 as your target? Also, did you restart eclipse after updation of sdks?

Answer (score 6):

right click project --> go to properties --> select Android from there --> and from the list of target name select Android 4.0 or lesser

Comment: My above error got solved, but "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configchanges" is popping again

Comment: open your AndroidManifest.xml

<activity android:name=".AdActivity" />

try add this code

Comment: I added that but its not working