# Processing - error

Tags: android, processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error:Unable to resolve target ‘android-2’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942144/errorunable-to-resolve-target-android-2)

I'm using Processing in android mode. I always get the following error which I have no clue on how to fix. I have the latest version of android installed (16).

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:517: Unable to resolve project target 'android-10'

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4942201/1401257

Answer (score 3):

Double check you have API 10 installed through your Android SDK manager.

Comment: Why is it necessary to have version 10 installed?

Comment: Because you are targeting it.